# Mysql database design one table many key value rows performance?

Tags: mysql, design-patterns

Most of the content types and categories of a project I'm working on has many tables related to each content, pages, blog_articles, blog_tags, recipes, recipes_categories, ads, banners, covers, customers etc.

What all this tables have in common and repeated in each table is title, slug, description, only few of them have other fields, like recipes has ingredients|methods|level_of_difficulty and so on.

What I was thinking is to get rid of many tables and narrow it down to only two tables, kind of like wordpress for posts and postmeta.

For example

```
content_table
-------------
id
parent_id
type
title
slug
body

content_meta
-------------
id
content_id
type
key
value
```

In the content_meta I was thinking to do something like this

```
content_meta
----------------------------------------------------------
| id | content_id | type   | key         | value
----------------------------------------------------------
| 1  | 1          | banner | image       | img.jpg
| 2  | 1          | banner | link_to     | google.com
| 3  | 2          | recipe | ingredient  | milk
| 4  | 2          | recipe | method      | stir it 
| 5  | 2          | recipe | difficulty  | medium
```

I'm very well aware that for only few types of content the content meta table is going to grow quick

What do you think of this type of design from performance point of view and should I drop it?

Comment: performance will be crap, since you're negating the primary purpose of being able to use a relational database: RELATING DATA. you won't be able to easily (or at all) `join`, or use aggregate functions, blah blah blah. essentially you're turning your fancy DBMS into a stupid key-value storage system.

Comment: I understand that, so wordpress is doing the same thing then, NEGATING RELATING DATA?

Comment: not saying this is always a bad idea. if you have unstructured data, then going key-value store is about the only practical way of using a db to store it. but in general, if you ARE going to be expecting to do joins/aggregates, then don't go key-value. use a properly designed/normalized relational setup.

Comment: @MarcB how about performance and storage, I'm curious why wordpress is using this design pattern, I tried to find out why and couldn't find much, I know the cons and pros but how about performance?. Since you have a nice reputation perhaps you could explain my curiosity a bit?

Comment: it's useful for arbitrary storage, e.g. a keyword system. there's an infinite number of potential keywords, and you don't want to waste table space defining a column for every possible one. so you go with `id, name, value`. but this kind of key/value pairing is heavily abused by people building "enterprise" software: http://thedailywtf.com/articles/The_Inner-Platform_Effect

Comment: @MarcB I appreciate taking the time and finding this piece of article that made my mind clear about all this :) thank you

Answer (score 0):

It would be a better idea to either merge some tables or remove the redundant columns.

The content_meta idea could make for some pretty nasty queries later on, that concept would likely used when the "key" is dynamic. You'll have to rely on multiple subqueries (or JOINs) for each field in the content_meta table, instead of a single query.

```
SELECT title, body, ingredient, method FROM content_table 
INNER JOIN recipes ON content_table.content_id = recipes.content_id

VS

SELECT title, body, rIngredient.value 'ingredient', rMethod.value 'method' FROM content_table
LEFT JOIN content_meta rIngredient ON content_table.content_id = rIngredient.content_id AND type = 'recipe' AND key = 'ingredient'
LEFT JOIN content_meta rMethod ON content_table.content_id = rMethod.content_id AND type = 'recipe' AND key = 'method'
```

You may want to look into database normalization: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: it makes all the sense, I'll stick to usual guns, nothing futuristic